# Rails 5 debug asset compiling

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-5

How do you debug assets compiling in Rails 5?

Using Chrome, I don't get very useful error messages. If I run `rake assets:precompile` from the command line, it also fails, and doesn't quite help me enough either.

The problem I am having started during my upgrade from Rails 4.2 to 5. In application.css.scss, I have `@import "nifty"`. `nifty.scss` lives in vendor/assets/stylesheets/nifty along with the other SCSS files used for the nifty theme. The gist of `nifty.scss` is:

```
@import "_variables";
@import "_layout";
@import "_animations";
@import "_mainnav";
```

When Rails tries to compile the assets, it fails with @import _animations with the error `Undefined variable: "$enable-animation"`. Although, this variable is defined in `_variables;`. Even though I shouldn't need to, I have played around with adding `@import _variables;` at the top of _animations. This fixes that error, but then other very similar errors more errors come along until I pretty much @import every scss in every other scss file.

I'm thinking that the problem is not with variables in the SASS files, but a problem somewhere else. I've tried putting `byebug` as a breakpoint elsewhere, but can't seem to find the problems.

Is there another way to debug the asset pipeline and asset compilation?

Comment: Let us know the full stack trace. Do this `rake assets:precompile --trace`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I can help.

### Debugging Sprockets

You could try debugging **Spockets** or the **GEM** involved in the *Asset Pipeline*.
RVM is a hidden folder, your gems depending on the version you are using of *Ruby* could be inside the following path.

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/
```

Inside there I was able to find sprockets-rails-3.2.0, you have several **.rb files** that you can open with your sublime editor and you can set a breakpoint in the code with for example `binding.pry`.
Check the *pry gem* for details on the pry debugger.

I hope somethings comes to my mind for your other problems...

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find a good way to solve my problem. Instead I created a new Rails 5 app, then slowly moved over files handling errors as they went across. My advice would be to not upgrade from Rails 4 to Rails 5, but instead create a new app and move files.